# Screenshot.png not showing up

Tags: images, themes

My screenshot.png was working fine then all of a sudden doesn't show up. I've changed the permissions to 777. If I put mysite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/screenshot.png in the browser, the image doesn't show up, yet I'm 100% sure the image is the right spot in the theme root folder.  I've scoured many articles and can't find a fix.

[image]

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. If there is no image in your folder it won't show up in your theme preview. It seems the file has been accidentally deleted and you need to upload it again.

Comment: If it's not showing up when you access it directly, that suggests that it's not there, and you might be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @JacobPeattie this is the correct path where it should be yes? "mysite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/screenshot.png"

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the file extension to .jpg instead of .png;
I had this issue as well, and for some reason it won't accept .png but .jpg

Comment: thanks great idea. I did it but still not showing up. Something tells me I have to change some html now from Screenshot.png to Screenshot.jpg now that I changed the file from a png to a jpg. Know where to do that?